# How to show error message when using flock if not able to get lock on the file

Tags: linux, bash

My bash code look likes:

```
  set -e
  (
     flock -n 9
     main $@
   ) 9>/var/lock/mylockfile
```

But currently it don't show any error message, if it is not able to get lock on the file. 
Is there a way to show error message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With "set -e", you can use the ERR signal.  As said in the man page of bash
(description of the "set" command with option "-e"):

```
"A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits."
```

So you can try something like:

```
set -e
(
  trap 'echo flock failed.' ERR
  flock -n 9
  trap - ERR   # reset ERR trap
  main $@
) 9>/var/lock/mylockfile
```

Answer (score 2):

The example in the manpage says:

```
(
     flock -n 9 || exit 1
     # ... commands executed under lock ...
   ) 9>/var/lock/mylockfile
```

ie it exits if flock fails -- why don't you just use that?
If you want to display an error, you could try this:

```
(
         # paranoia: flock may fail with an exit code other than 1,
         # eg if it can't be found in $PATH
         if flock -n 9 ; then
           do_stuff
         else
           show_error
         fi
) 9>$lockfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check for the return code of `flock -n`

```
 set -e
  (
     flock -n 9
     if [ "$?" -eq 1 ] ; then 
        echo "could not lock"
        exit 1
     fi
     main $@
   ) 9>/var/lock/mylockfile
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
lock="/tmp/name_of_lockfile.lck"
echo "Lockfile $lock"
exec 200>$lock
/usr/bin/flock -n --verbose 200 || exit 1
```

So when running succesfull

```
Lockfile /tmp/name_of_lockfile.lck
flock: getting lock took 0.000006 seconds
```

and not succesfull

```
Lockfile /tmp/name_of_lockfile.lck
flock: failed to get lock
```